# XML parsing in parse cloud code with node-xmlreader

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, xml-parsing, parse-cloud-code, xmlreader

I have a XML data and I want to parse it in parse cloud code with node-xmlreader : https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-xmlreader

But it returns that error :

http://i.hizliresim.com/pBN01z.png

How can i fix it?

Here is my xml data :

http://i.hizliresim.com/bJErJ0.png

and my cloud code :

```
var test = [];
xmlreader.read(httpResponse.text, function (err, res) {

       if(err)
           return response.error("hata");

       for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
               test[i] = res.Envelope.Body.GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult.listitems.data.row.at(i).text();
   }
      response.success(test.toString());

});
```